# Ошибка Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist (Laravel 10)

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;
namespace App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

// use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
    /**
    * Seed the application's database.
    */

    public function run(): void {
        User::factory( 100 )->create();
    }
}
```

Как и полагается, находится в App\database\seeders

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```

в composer вроде тоже все нормально, composer dump-autoload запускал и все равно одна и та же проблема

Comment: Чего у Вас там неймспейс два раза объявлен?

Comment: Хаха, даже не заметил, должен был быть use, спасибо :D